# При попытке настройки конвертации .scss в .css с помощью команды --watch появляется ошибка

Tags: ruby, sass

Ошибка:

> Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM866
>   and UTF-8

после этого ещё вылезает сообщение:

> --trace for backtrace.

Как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: На какой ОС? Чем собирается? Какой полный путь к файлу `.scss`?

Comment: windows vista, установил Ruby, создал необходимые папку и директории scss  и css, index.html. в командной строке прописал : >MySass>sass scss/style.scss css/style.css  нажал enter, всё хорошо скомпилировалось, а вот когда ввожу: >MySass>sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css  - выдает ошибку

Comment: Полный путь до папки с `.scss`-файлом какой?

Comment: спасибо, что потыкали носом в полный путь до папки. там действительно одна папка имела кириллицу. исправил, всё заработало. стыдно, не то слово, допускать такие ошибки

Comment: Да бывает. Отредактируйте в вопрос, что имеете дело с Windows и напишите ответ о том, как починили. Там, может, и репутации капнет. А ещё рекомендую такие вещи делать под Linux. Хотя бы виртуальным.